# Require Nested Params in Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested, parameters

I need to know how to require nested params in a Ruby on Rails API. I have my method set up for the param whitelisting as below:

```
def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :profile => [:name, :birthdate, :addy])
end
```

However, that makes profile a permitted param, not a required one. I want profile to be required. It's allowed to have no other nested params (essentially everything nil), but must still be required. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Inside the Model, you can put a vaildation to make `profile` attribute as _required_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the "required" portion is going to come from your actual model. So, in this case, go to your user.rb file and add the following.

`validates :profile, presence: true`

Is that what you're talking about? Usually, you're going to want to allow params in the controller and perform validations and stuff in the actual model file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make multiple items required in the controller you can add them like so:

```
   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(...)
     params.require(:profile).permit(...)
   end
```

[Rails strong parameters documentation in github](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#require-multiple-parameters)